# Can a FAT32 and NTFS file system exist without UUID?

Tags: filesystems, udev

I have an USB disk drive partioned with 2 FAT32 partitions, which is not getting detected in the embedded device, but gets detected in a Fedora system.

Basically in the udev rules, I am not able to get the UUID of the USB disk. Is it possible to have a filesystem FAT32/NTFS to exist without having UUIDs?

Comment: `blkid` generates a UUID for the filesystem. As far as I know, it always generates something sensible and reproducible. Your problem is unrelated to UUID: it seems that the drive or its partitions aren't detected on your embedded device. What unix variant is it running? What is the output of `cat /proc/partitions`, and do you recognize the drive there? Do any messages appear in the system logs when you plug in the drive? What is the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` where `sdX` is the block device (probably `sdb` or `sdc`)? What about `udevadm info -a -n sdX`?